# Could not get receive sequence from COM port's RX line in docklight

Tags: docklight

I used a RS232 to connect my pc and VALHALLA 4300C, and used Docklight software to explore it.  I went through a sample project: PingPong.ptp, I followed the instruction and I did not get any data back. I could only see the TX info but not RX info. (NOTE: the reason that I used 4300C is because I just explore Docklight and I can only have access to 4300C for the moment.)
Here is the link to the instruction of the sample project.  It is REALLY short. 
http://docklight.de/manual/index.html
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We are actually making docklight, and I believe I can help you: The "pingpong" sample is not useful for what you try. It's intended for a test where you want to know if your computer's RS232 interface is ok and working at all. For "PingPong", you use a "loopback" / shortcut where you directly short the  TX with the RX pin. But I can make you a small example project for the "VALHALLA 4300C" showing you how to get basic information out of the device. Just give me a few hours time, I'll post an answer. Oliver

Comment: Can I ask a question? What RS232 interface do you have on your PC side? A regular USB-to-RS232 dongle? (these should work fine with Docklight and the  VALHALLA device)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, the PingPong example is not suitable for the application you have with the VALHALLA 4300C. The 4300C will not respond to a "Ping" text it does not understand.

Here is how I suggest you get started communicating with your VALHALLA 4300C from a Windows PC.

- Start Docklight (but also any other plain text terminal like Realterm, Teraterm oder YAT should work, of course).
- Select the COM port number that is your actual RS232 interface on your PC. (Docklight displays a dropdown list of available ports and their descriptions.)
- Set the serial port settings to **9600 baud, no parity, 8 data bits, one stop bit** (see the [Valhalla 4300C Manual](https://valhallascientific.com/manuals/4300C_Manual.pdf) on page 6-15).
- Open the COM port and send a command the VALHALLA 4300C understands, e.g. ***IDN?** followed by a **CR** (carriage return) and **LF** (line feed). Refer to the [4300C Manual](https://valhallascientific.com/manuals/4300C_Manual.pdf) from 6-18 for the full command list.
- You can use the [ValhallaScientific_4300C_Example.ptp](http://docklight.de/exampleFiles/devices/ValhallaScientific_4300C_Example.zip) Docklight example project I created: Download it, open it by double-click, adjust the COM1 port number to what is the actual COM port for your PC's RS232 interface. Then click on the "IDN" Send Sequence to send a query about Manufacturer & model details.

[image: Docklight COM port number and serial settings (baud, parity, ..)]

[image: Sending example data sequence (no actual 4300C connected for this demo)]

Comment: Hi Oliver, sorry for the late response.  You are so helpful.  Now it is working.  Thank you so much!

Comment: thanks for confirming this actually works.(since we don't have the actual device here).We're always happy to help out.